# Bind rows by by select column names from a list?

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list of date frames:

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25,"Gender" = rep(c("Male","Female"),25))
y <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25,"Occupation" = rep(c("Barber","Doctor"),25))
z <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25)
list <- c(x,y,z)
```

I am attempting to bind the data frames together into one data frame, unlisted. I want to pull only specific columns to make the end data frame however.

So for instance, I want x,y, and z combined into one data frame with only SN and Age in the resulting data frame.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Should your fourth line be `lst <- list(x, y, z)` perhaps? Your question title suggests that.

Comment: No, I want to manipulate the list created in the example to produce a single data frame of the combined data frames, with only SN and Age selected.

Comment: @markus You can use `c` too, it does the same thing. Maybe not the best for readability though

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just wasn't sure if that was intended or not.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want a general solution that will also work when you have more than three elements in your list of dataframes:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25,"Gender" = rep(c("Male","Female"),25))
y <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25,"Occupation" = rep(c("Barber","Doctor"),25))
z <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25)
lst <- list(x,y,z)

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, select, SN, Age))
```

Answer (score 4):

An approach with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
lst %>% map_dfr(`[`, c("SN", "Age"))
```

Which says, map the extract `[` function over the items "SN" and "Age" from each list, then bind together all those elements into a data.frame `df` -- and hey, while you're binding them together, please bind the ***r***ows so `dfr`.

Comment: Or `lst %>% map_dfr(select, SN, Age)` if you're using `dplyr` too

Answer (score 3):

Is this simple enough?

```
xyz <- bind_rows(select(x, SN, Age), select(y, SN, Age), select(z, SN, Age))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't got your question, but this helps?

```
bind_rows( (x %>% select(SN, Age)), (y %>% select(SN, Age)), z)
    SN Age
1    1   1
2    2   2
3    3   3
4    4   4
5    5   5
6    6   6
7    7   7
8    8   8
9    9   9
10  10  10
11  11  11
12  12  12
13  13  13
14  14  14
15  15  15
16  16  16
17  17  17
18  18  18
19  19  19
20  20  20
21  21  21
22  22  22
23  23  23
24  24  24
25  25  25
26   1   1
27   2   2
28   3   3
29   4   4
30   5   5
31   6   6
32   7   7
33   8   8
34   9   9
35  10  10
36  11  11
37  12  12
38  13  13
39  14  14
40  15  15
41  16  16
42  17  17
43  18  18
44  19  19
45  20  20
46  21  21
47  22  22
48  23  23
49  24  24
50  25  25
51   1   1
52   2   2
53   3   3
54   4   4
55   5   5
56   6   6
57   7   7
58   8   8
59   9   9
60  10  10
61  11  11
62  12  12
63  13  13
64  14  14
65  15  15
66  16  16
67  17  17
68  18  18
69  19  19
70  20  20
71  21  21
72  22  22
73  23  23
74  24  24
75  25  25
76   1   1
77   2   2
78   3   3
79   4   4
80   5   5
81   6   6
82   7   7
83   8   8
84   9   9
85  10  10
86  11  11
87  12  12
88  13  13
89  14  14
90  15  15
91  16  16
92  17  17
93  18  18
94  19  19
95  20  20
96  21  21
97  22  22
98  23  23
99  24  24
100 25  25
101  1   1
102  2   2
103  3   3
104  4   4
105  5   5
106  6   6
107  7   7
108  8   8
109  9   9
110 10  10
111 11  11
112 12  12
113 13  13
114 14  14
115 15  15
116 16  16
117 17  17
118 18  18
119 19  19
120 20  20
121 21  21
122 22  22
123 23  23
124 24  24
125 25  25
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution that will work with any `data.table` that has any number of columns. It lines up the columns based on their names, and fills any blanks with `NA` where needed. You will can always use that same approach for any number of data.tables.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25,"Gender" = rep(c("Male","Female"),25))
y <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25,"Occupation" = rep(c("Barber","Doctor"),25))
z <- data.frame("SN" = 1:25,"Age" = 1:25)

listy <- list(x,y,z)

a <- rbindlist(listy,
               use.names = TRUE,
               fill = TRUE) %>% 
  .[, .(SN, Age)]
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
lst <- c(x,y,z)
```

it turns out that we can do

```
out <- unstack(stack(lst))
head(out)
#  SN Age
#1  1   1
#2  2   2
#3  3   3
#4  4   4
#5  5   5
#6  6   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Too simple? Are Age and SB always in the 1 and 2 spot?

```
list <- as.data.frame(c(x[1:2],y[1:2],z[1:2]))
```

Comment: I think that would work in this particular example. The actual data has hundreds of columns that may not be in the same order. They should have the same column names for a given variable though.

Answer (score 0):

I approached it the same way as igorkf but set my syntax slightly differently:

```
xyz <- x %>% select(SN, age) %>%      
    bind_rows(y %>% select(SN, age) %>%       
    bind_rows(z %>% select(SN, age))
```